# Aggregate values from a data table into a new table present in the same sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have two tables. In the first table I have entries and their amount, entries can repeat according to the date entered. The second column contains their count. In the second table I need to get a consolidated count for each entry.

I want to make a formula that will sum all the related entries from the first table and put them into the second table. Here is an excample of what I need:

**First Table**

Item Name          Items Received

Office files                 5

Stapler                                 1

Rims                       1

Office files                 5

Rims                       1

Office files                 5

Rims                       1

**Second Table**

Item Name          Total Items

Office files                 15

Stapler                                 1

Rims                       3

Please note that both the tables are in the same sheet. And yes I know I can come up with a solution using PivotTable, however I need another solution.

Comment: Why do you not want to use a pivot table?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of having a summing table, build a [Pivot Table](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/pivottable-reports-101-HA001034632.aspx)

Select your main table range, go to table options, select Summarise with Pivot Table and then place the pivot table wherever you want.

You can then drag the items column into the Rows section and the Sum of items into the Values.

[image: Table to Pivot]

In the image above you can see the raw data table on the left, the resulting pivot table to the right of that, and then to the far right is the fields list for the pivot table.

Comment: You are right currently I am doing that way but it shows me the result in a new sheet which I want to avoid. Is there a way to do the way I am thinking?

Comment: @AmeerMoaaviah, when you click Summarize as Pivot Table there are two settings in the pop-up window; the first is where the data is, the second is where the table should go. By default this goes to a new sheet but you can select Existing Sheet and the select a cell and sheet of your choice. If you already have the pivot table built just select it all, cut it and paste it to where you want it.

Comment: Did you manage to get this to work for you in the end @AmeerMoaaviah?

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid a pivot table (but it really is the best method for your issue).

1. Copy/paste the "Item Name" column to a new column, then "Remove Duplicates".
2. Use the SUMIF formula.

See the graphic below.

[image]